# UWP ListView in ContentDialog not scrolling

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

C# UWP Windows 10

This is a XAML code of my contentdialog:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    .....

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView x:Name="MerchantList"                
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MerchantListViewTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedValue="{Binding currItemId, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I need to show List of some items to user, but ListView not scrolling. How to fix it?

Comment: Tried using ListView without using any of that extra configuration like ScrollViewer. If I'm not mistaken, as long as there is to much data, ListView is always scrollable, after that you can pass one by one the parameter to see which one blocked the scroll. Ow, you can tried it using stackpanel too.

Comment: Try giving height to ListView and see whether it scrolls

Comment: Not working either Archana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set some "non-Auto" size of columns and rows (pixels or stars, doesn't matter). I really wasn't able to find out any reason of this behavior in documentation, but in my case it helped.

Comment: sorry how did you do that? can you write an example? I set Height to ListviewItem, but it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  This is really strange.  Changing the RowDefinition height of the ListView row from "auto" to "*" has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView x:Name="MerchantList"                
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MerchantListViewTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        SelectedValue="{Binding currItemId, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedValuePath="Id"
        ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

try this ....